# Php preg_match m3u8 token

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to pull the m3u8 file from a site.

**This is the site address.**

http://uygulama14.club/token/sinema/beinmoviespremier.php?idd=

**The code I use:**

```
<?php
$link = "http://uygulama14.club/token/sinema/beinmoviespremier.php?idd=";
$veri = file_get_contents($link);
preg_match('#m3u8(.*?)"#',$veri,$veritemp);
//echo $veritemp[1];
//print_r($veritemp[1]);
function go ($url, $time = 0){
        if ($time) header("Refresh: {$time}; url={$url}");
        else header("Location: {$url}");
    }

    go("http://a.bylig3.com:8081/taraftartv4/beinmoviespremier/playlist.m3u8$veritemp[1]");
?>
```

**Problem**: The connection I made is not working properly.
It works when you copy and edit it from your site.

```
{"result":[{"url":"http:\/\/a.bylig3.com:8081\/taraftartv4\/beinmoviespremier\/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9My8yMi8yMDE5IDU6NTI6NDggQU0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1PNVRNcS9VUkx6NEp3elFoOG01eUtBPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTIw"}]}
```

I'm copying the url section from the site.
I'm editing the url part in this way and it works

http://a.bylig3.com:8081/taraftartv4/beinmoviespremier/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9My8yMi8yMDE5IDU6NTI6NDggQU0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1PNVRNcS9VUkx6NEp3elFoOG01eUtBPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTIw

But not working with the preg_match command.

Comment: "The connection I made is not working properly" - be more descriptive. What happens, what fails? Http debugging? Why did you think preg_match is at fault? What did your `print_r` show?

Comment: <?php
$link = "http://uygulama14.club/token/sinema/beinmoviespremier.php?idd=";
$veri = file_get_contents($link);
preg_match('#m3u8(.*?)"#',$veri,$veritemp);
print_r(http://a.bylig3.com:8081/taraftartv4/beinmoviespremier/playlist.m3u8$veritemp[1]);
?>The link I tried to pull is not working. working on their site